# "Reverse" type inference possible?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Given the following classes (factories used because C# doesn't support type inference on constructors):

```
public class A<T>
{
    public A(B<T> b) {  }
}

public class B<T>
{
    public B(C<T> c) {  }
}

public class C<T>
{
    public C(T tee) {  }
}

public class D<T>
{
    public static D<T> Create<V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> property)
    {
        return new D<T, V>(property);
    }
}

public class D<T, V> : D<T>
{
    public D(Expression<Func<T, V>> property) {  }
}

public class Model
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }

    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

public class AFactory
{
    public static A<T> Create<T>(B<T> bee)
    {
        return new A<T>(bee);
    }
}

public class BFactory
{
    public static B<T> Create<T>(C<T> cee)
    {
        return new B<T>(cee);
    }
}

public class CFactory
{
    public static C<T> Create<T>(params D<T>[] tees)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The following compiles:

```
AFactory.Create(BFactory.Create(CFactory.Create(
    D<Model>.Create(m => m.P1), D<Model>.Create(m => m.P2)
)));
```

The following **does not**:

```
AFactory.Create<Model>(BFactory.Create(CFactory.Create(
    D.Create(m => m.P1), D.Create(m => m.P2)
)));
```

The difference is that in the first example I'm specifying the type of the model on the innermost classes, so type inference works normally and propagates up the tree. The problem is that I then have to specify the model type on **every** `D.Create()` call, which seems redundant.

The second example is the way I'd **like** to write this code: tell the outermost class that its type is `Model` and all the classes that are being constructed use that type as well. Essentially, it's syntactic sugar for `AFactory.Create<Model>(BFactory.Create<Model>(/* turtles all the way down... */))`.

Is there any way to achieve this in C#? I've tried all the permutations of inheritance and type constraints that I can think of, but nothing has given me the desired result.

I'm also fully aware that I might be missing something fundamental about generics - please feel free to educate me if that's the case.

Comment: Type inference works from the inside out generally. Also, generic parameters for classes are generally not inferred like you expecting it to.

Comment: You are passing an ever greater collection of things in to `AFactory.Create` via a cascading parameter list. With that approach, `D<Model>.Create` is effectively the first thing specified and it's specified in a way that cannot pass useful info to `CFactory.Create`. If you turn it into a fluent (linked function) solution, then you need only specify the type once as the returned value from each function contains the type info for the next function. Something like `AFactory.Define<Model>().Containing().BFactory().Containing().CFactory().With<D>(m => m.P1).And(m => m.P2).Create()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Generic Type Inference in C# reflectively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495556/implementing-generic-type-inference-in-c-sharp-reflectively)