# Is there a way to get a type that is restricted by itself to be inferred automatically

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0, type-inference

```
public abstract class SampleClass<T> where T : SampleClass<T>
{
}

public class SampleClass1<T> : SampleClass<SampleClass1>
{
}

public class SampleClass2<T> : SampleClass<SampleClass2>
{
}
```

I know in Java these types could be inferred automatically, but for some reason in C# I have to specify the type if I try to use the abstract class inside a variable. e.g.

```
List<SampleClass> sampleClass = new List<SampleClass> // throws an error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Generic Type Inference in C# reflectively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495556/implementing-generic-type-inference-in-c-sharp-reflectively)